# missing column doesn't fail .filter?

Tags: python, pandas

Why doesn't `df.filter()` return a `KeyError` but `df[["a","d"]]` does?

I'm a pandas method-chainer, so I'd prefer to use `.filter()`. However, it's failure to fail can make debugging method chains a huge headache.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({"a": [1, 2, 3], "b": [4, 5, 6], "c": [7, 8, 9]})
df.filter(items=["a", "d"])
print(df)
```

```
    a
0   1
1   2
2   3
```

Comment: Because the devs coded it that way.  From the doc string `"Keep labels from axis which are in items."`  Don't use `filter` if you need it to fail.  Use `loc` or `df[cols_im_looking_for]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you can see in the Pandas Documentation (Source Code) [here](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/v1.0.3/pandas/core/generic.py#L4621-L4716) (line 4695 - 4699)

```
..
..

labels = self._get_axis(axis)

if items is not None:
    name = self._get_axis_name(axis)
    return self.reindex(**{name: [r for r in items if r in labels]})

..
..
```

where `items` is a parameter items we pass to the `filter` functions and `labels` is the list of columns.

It doesn't throw an error because of this line `[r for r in items if r in labels]` which means we only take the column name which available in the `labels` variable.